# How to refetch correct data in useInfiniteQuery() - react query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-query

I have a list of items and I'm using `useInfiniteQuery` for pagination stuff,
So I have a case where I can edit Item info then re-fetch the list again to get the updated list of items,

So I'm trying to re-fetch the list using
`refetchPage()` FC it works when I'm on the first page `1`

but

current behavior:

when I scroll down to page 2 "last page at this moment." then update the item when

- using `queryClient.refetchQueries`

it replaces the prev data with the re-fetched data on the current page.

```
 await queryClient.refetchQueries(['getUsualOrders'], {
                stale: true,
              });
```

- using `refetch()`.

  ```
  refetchUsualOrderList({
          refetchPage: (page, index) => {
            return index === 0;
          },
     });
  ```

it replaces the prev data with current page data without the updated data
Actually, it sends a request for the next page "that doesn't exist"

So how can i re-fetch the data and keep the previous data?

Code

Hook

```
export const useUsualOrders = ({lang, pageNumber = 1, token}) => {
  return useInfiniteQuery(
    ['getUsualOrders'],
    () => getUsualOrders({lang, pageNumber, token}),
    {
      getNextPageParam: lastPage => {
        if (lastPage.next !== null) {
          return lastPage.next;
        }
        return undefined;
      },
    },
  );
};
```

UI

```
const [currentPageNumber, setCurrentPageNumber] = useState(1);

 const {
    data: usualOrdersList,
    hasNextPage,
    fetchNextPage,
    isFetchingNextPage,
    refetch: refetchUsualOrderList,
  } = useUsualOrders({
    lang,
    token: currentUserInfo?.token,
    pageNumber: currentPageNumber,
  });

 const loadMore = () => {
    if (hasNextPage) {
      setCurrentPageNumber(prev => prev + 1);
      fetchNextPage();
    }
  };



  
const onRefetch = ()=>{
       refetchUsualOrderList({
            refetchPage: (page, index) => {
              return index === 0;
            },
          });
}

<FlatList
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={usualOrdersList.pages.map(page => page.results).flat()}
        renderItem={renderModelItems}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        onEndReached={loadMore}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.3}
        // refreshControl={
        //   <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
        // }
        style={{
          backgroundColor: secondary_bg_color,
        }}
        contentContainerStyle={[
          styles.modelList,
          {
            backgroundColor: secondary_bg_color,
            paddingHorizontal: PADDING_HORIZONTAL.SMALL,
          },
        ]}
        ListFooterComponent={
          isFetchingNextPage ? (
            <ActivityIndicator color={buttonBgColor} />
          ) : null
        }
      />
```

response body
[image: response body]

Comment: How do you use `refetchUsualOrderList` in your code?

Comment: @GabrielPichot i add an `onRefetch()` can u please check the code again?

Comment: Which version of `react-query` are you using? (I don't see `refetchPage` option in `refetch` in v3 and v4).

Comment: @GabrielPichot `v3` look at this 
https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/guides/infinite-queries#refetchpage

Comment: `So how can i re-fetch the data and keep the previous data?` You mean refetch the current page and keep other pages? BTW, `return index === 0` isn't this mean refetch only first page?